# Need to restart ssh after it is killed in remote host

Tags: python, ssh, process, signals, pexpect

I am doing an ssh to a remote (linux) machine using `pexpect in python`.

My script needs to keep running always to get some logs from the remote machine. For some reason, periodically all ssh connections are killed using `pkill` by the admin of the remote machine (This cannot be changed).

The pkill on the remote machine kills my local ssh and my script exits. How do I restart my ssh in my code and continue my script?

I thought that the local process on my machine would receive a sigh-up from the remote machine when it kills the ssh process.

But that does not seem to be the case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably example of bash script will suit you. I used `wait` in example script below. Just have checked it, worked for me.

This will rise `ssh` connection again and again on the local machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "YourPassword" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server &

while true
do
  wait `pidof ssh`
  sshpass -p "YourPassword" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server
done
```

whenever a server runs :

`sudo pkill sshd`

the connection will be raised up again.

If you don't have `sshpass` then install it:

`sudo apt-get install sshpass`

Comment: I was looking for a Python solution actually. This works too. But I was able to do it with just exception handling. Whenever the process was killed, I was able to catch the exception and call my function which recreated the ssh handles I needed.